# Interface<dynamic> not allowed in C# - workaround

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, interface, clr

I have a class that I am trying to design which uses `dynamic` as type parameter:

```
public class Idea : IEnumerable<dynamic>, IQueryable<dynamic>
{
}
```

> **Compiler: Cannot implement a dynamic interface**

So I have this workaround which I'm not overly keen on:

```
public class Idea<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
}

public class Idea : Idea<dynamic>
{
}
```

> **Compiler: success!**

I can't think of any other way to work around this issue, and I'm not really sure I want to expose `Idea<T>` to the user.

Questions:

1. I feel like there are code smells here... can you confirm?
2. Why does the CLR not allow implementation of `dynamic` interfaces?
3. Are there any patterns I could use to achieve this without exposing `Idea<T>`?

Comment: Since `T` must be known at compile time and `dynamic` is inferred at run time, why wouldn't you prefer to expose `Idea<T>`?

Comment: @AndreiV because 'Idea' is dynamic by design, so Idea<T> (for example Idea<int>) doesn't make much sense. Idea<T> could have its uses but they would be limited.

Comment: You can use `dynamic` to store `int`s as well, whether it makes sense or not. I understand the "design" part, but as I see it, your problem here is purely semantic. Would `public class Idea : IEnumerable<object>, IQueryable<object>` be much different?

Comment: @AndreiV I tried that too, but say for example I want to do .Where(x => x == 1) ...this does not work because x is object not int (for example)

Comment: @AndreiV, post your comment as answer since it makes much sense.

Comment: Also, with `IEnumerable<dynamic>` do you think you can use a `where` constraint? think of it.

Comment: You can implement `IEnumerable<object>` with `public IEnumerator<dynamic> GetEnumerator()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had like to address your foremost question "Why does the CLR not allow implementation of dynamic interfaces?"

Simply because it doesn't make sense. Read this [blog post of Chris Burrows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2009/02/04/c-dynamic-part-vii.aspx) that explains that thoroughly.

There are for example problems when overriding `dynamic` members, matching signatures, etc.

For example this line says a lot:

> but it’s because when we look at method overrides and overloads, **we treat object and dynamic as the same**

Yeah, that is an issue. This sample was given in the article:

```
public class C
{
    public void M(object x) { }
    public void M(dynamic x) { }
}
```

That indeed doesn't make sense, and although the types seem to differ, in the CLR world they don't.

Although it seems to be possible, according to the CLI team, this needs a lot of more work to do. And they didn't find this useful to implement until now:

> The metadata team reported that a reading of the CLI spec seemed to indicate that the tables for interface implementations and custom attributes **might have permitted it**, but anyway no one we know of has ever done this, and it would have been effort expended. **We have priorities and a limited budget of time, and this didn’t make the cut.**

To answer your other questions: Yes, you are right, the workaround feels bad, and it probably is, but it seems the only workable solution right now. Ask yourself if you really want and need this. If so, proceed with your current solution.

Comment: Patrick, is it also not the case that; spec says in case of `IEnumerable<T>` the `T` always gets closed at compile time (though the actual synthesis may happen at run time). That's all generic type are closed at compile time but if I say `IEnumerable<dynamic>` it doesn't look to be closed at compile time and so compiler won't allow it to pass through. Anyways, +1 nice answer and with a nice link.

Comment: @Rahul: Thanks. Feel free to edit out unclarity if you think it needs it.